# Converting WebDriver.current_url into string in python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Im currently trying to get a webpage url converted into a string so that it could be put into a html format

```
  for x in range(3):

        wDriver.get('https://www.example.com/')
        sTitle = wDriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div['+str(i)+']/div[1]/div[1]/h2[1]/a[1]')
        sTitle.click()
        link = wDriver.current_url
        sHeader = wDriver.find_element_by_class_name('c-page-title')
        print(sHeader.text + ' ' + link)
        i=i+1
        newLink = str(link)
        time.sleep(2)
    
        
        sReturn = sReturn + '<p><a href="'+newLink+'">'+sHeader+'</a></p>'
```

The error code I get is

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WebElement") to str"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link = wDriver.current_url
```

current_url returns a string, so link is already a string. You do not need to explicitly convert to string again.

The reason why you are getting this exception

```
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WebElement") to str"
```

is cause when you look here

```
sReturn = sReturn + '<p><a href="'+newLink+'">'+sHeader+'</a></p>'
```

newLink is a string, so no issue with that, but `sHeader` is a web element. That is what causing the issue.

Please use `.text` to extract the text :

```
sReturn = sReturn + '<p><a href="'+newLink+'">'+sHeader.text+'</a></p>'
```

or in case for any reason you would like to have it stored in a variable then use :

```
sHeader = wDriver.find_element_by_class_name('c-page-title').text
sReturn = sReturn + '<p><a href="'+newLink+'">'+sHeader+'</a></p>'
```